# Не подключается к базе данных MS Access

Tags: c#

При попытке подключения к БД выдается ошибка: "ОШИБКА [IM002] [Microsoft] [Диспетчер драйверов ODBC] Имя источника данных не найдено и не указан драйвер по умолчанию".
Используемая строка подключения: "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=Database1.mdb"

Comment: Проверьте, действительно ли драйвер в системе имеет именно такое имя. Должен быть, по идее, `Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};`. Или у Вас ну настолько древняя система?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/sqldriverconnect-access-driver?view=sql-server-ver15  Пример строки подключения (путь к базе см.): Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=c:\\temp\\sample.mdb